# What version UBUNTU is best

Tags: 12.04

I have a netbook MSI U135 DDR 2 1GB with Windows7 Starter. I want to install, alongside it, a Ubuntu version which is stable and fast running. Can anyone tell me which one to install?And to install Ubuntu alongside windows7 Starter, how to procede?

Greetz Chris.

Comment: And "best" is subjective. And as a bonus: guess why we have a live dvd?

Comment: You should use a LTS version if you want stability. LTS stands for "long time support". If you want cutting edge features and you accept that some packages are broken, then you can use the most recent version. Anyways it would be best to learn first how to save all packages in case you need to upgrade from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the hardware of a **netbook** MSI U135.
You must use a 32 bit Linux distro, I **suggest** a lightweight Ubuntu derivative.

- Linux [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is a great alternative to Ubuntu for PC with **very** low resources or with very resource consuming tasks, I use it on my EeePC; this distribution uses [Pcmanfm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMan_File_Manager) and [Openbox](http://openbox.org/), two light graphical applications to manage your desktop (which is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/)).
- If you need more default "desktop"/user-friendly functionalities then use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) (that features, of course, [xfce](http://www.xfce.org/?lang=en)).

Please, follow the [Official Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/installation-guide/amd64/) to install any of the Ubuntu derivatives or Ubuntu itself. Follow the specific distribution site to find a specialized community for any of your doubts.
Remember to update your system (at least do the security updates) after a fresh install of any Linux/*nix distribution.
Use the "LTS" version only if you want to install a new system on a production machine, because these versions aren't updated very frequently and may have different versions of the kernel.
Please, feel free to comment down here if you need more help.

Have a nice experience.